# LOG4J: Modify logged message using custom appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

For security reasons, I need to look at every logged message in my app and possibly modify it before it goes to the log file. I figured I could write a custom appender (extending DailyRollingFileAppender) and override subAppend(LoggingEvent event). Problem is, there's no setter for the message text in LoggingEvent, and the message is a private attribute. I could create a new LoggingEvent with my modified message, but the API doesn't make it easy to copy over the rest of the original LoggingEvent. It all seems designed to discourage meddling with the message in a custom appender.

The only other option I can see is to modify hundreds of logging statements to call a new global method that can modify the text first and then make the Log4J call. I'd rather not!

Has anyone else had the need to modify the logged message in a custom appender?

Answer (score 14):

I'm not entirely sure why creating a new `LoggingEvent` is so onerous. This seems to work for me:

```
package test.logging;

import org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class MyDailyRollingFileAppender extends DailyRollingFileAppender {

    @Override
    protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
        String modifiedMessage = String.format("**** Message modified by MyDailyRollingFileAppender ****\n\n%s\n\n**** Finished modified message ****", event.getMessage());
        LoggingEvent modifiedEvent = new LoggingEvent(event.getFQNOfLoggerClass(), event.getLogger(), event.getTimeStamp(), event.getLevel(), modifiedMessage,
                                                      event.getThreadName(), event.getThrowableInformation(), event.getNDC(), event.getLocationInformation(),
                                                      event.getProperties());

        super.subAppend(modifiedEvent);
    }

}
```

With this test:

```
package test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLogging {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestLogging.class);
        log.info("I am testing my logging");
        log.info("Here is an exception", new Exception());
    }

}
```

and this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="MyDailyRollingFileAppender" class="test.logging.MyDailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="File" value="mine.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="MyDailyRollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I am getting the following output:

```
2011-10-14 10:09:09,322 INFO  () [main] TestLogging - **** Message modified by MyDailyRollingFileAppender ****

I am testing my logging

**** Finished modified message ****
2011-10-14 10:09:09,333 INFO  () [main] TestLogging - **** Message modified by MyDailyRollingFileAppender ****

Here is an exception

**** Finished modified message ****
java.lang.Exception
    at test.TestLogging.main(TestLogging.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Although I have done something similar to this, I used a slightly different approach. Instead of writing subclasses of each type of `Appender` I wanted to use, I created an `Appender` which wraps other `Appender` objects, and modifies the message before sending to the wrapped `Appender`s.  Something like this:

```
package test.logging;

import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.AppenderAttachable;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAppenderWrapper extends AppenderSkeleton implements AppenderAttachable {

    private final List<Appender> appenders = new ArrayList<Appender>();

    public void close() {
        synchronized (appenders) {
            for (Appender appender : appenders) {
                appender.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }

    public void addAppender(Appender appender) {
        synchronized (appenders) {
            appenders.add(appender);
        }
    }

    public Enumeration getAllAppenders() {
        return Collections.enumeration(appenders);
    }

    public Appender getAppender(String name) {
        synchronized (appenders) {
            for (Appender appender : appenders) {
                if (appender.getName().equals(name)) {
                    return appender;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isAttached(Appender appender) {
        synchronized (appenders) {
            for (Appender wrapped : appenders) {
                if (wrapped.equals(appender)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void removeAllAppenders() {
        synchronized (appenders) {
            appenders.clear();
        }
    }

    public void removeAppender(Appender appender) {
        synchronized (appenders) {
            for (Iterator<Appender> i = appenders.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                if (i.next().equals(appender)) {
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeAppender(String name) {
        synchronized (appenders) {
            for (Iterator<Appender> i = appenders.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                if (i.next().getName().equals(name)) {
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        String modifiedMessage = String.format("**** Message modified by MyAppenderWrapper ****\n\n%s\n\n**** Finished modified message ****", event.getMessage());
        LoggingEvent modifiedEvent = new LoggingEvent(event.getFQNOfLoggerClass(), event.getLogger(), event.getTimeStamp(), event.getLevel(), modifiedMessage,
                                                      event.getThreadName(), event.getThrowableInformation(), event.getNDC(), event.getLocationInformation(),
                                                      event.getProperties());

        synchronized (appenders) {
            for (Appender appender : appenders) {
                appender.doAppend(modifiedEvent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which you could configure like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="StdOut" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="File" value="mine.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%x) [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AppenderWrapper" class="test.logging.MyAppenderWrapper">
        <appender-ref ref="StdOut"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="AppenderWrapper"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

That way the message is still sent to the original appenders but with the modified message.

Comment: It works because you're using version 1.2.15+. Previous log4j versions did not have some of the methods you use in your examples, hence the author's trouble. Many projects use the version 1.2.14, as it used to be the latest for a long time.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.2.16 and was able to use your example for creating a new LoggingEvent. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Thats how I did since I am working with an older version of log4j

Instead of customizing appender, I customized the layout and referred that layout in whichever Appender i needed this feature

```
public class LogValidatorLayout extends PatternLayout {

    public LogValidatorLayout() {
        super();
    }

    public LogValidatorLayout(String pattern) {
        super(pattern);
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {

        // only process String type messages
        if (event.getMessage() != null && event.getMessage() instanceof String) {

            String message = event.getMessage().toString();
            message = StringUtils.trim("Some custom text --->>"+message);

            // earlier versions of log4j don't provide any way to update messages,
            // so use reflections to do this
            try {
                Field field = LoggingEvent.class.getDeclaredField("message");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(event, message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Dont log it as it will lead to infinite loop. Simply print the trace
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return super.format(event);
    }

}
```

And in your log4j.properties or xml, register this Layout

```
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=a.b.c.package.LogValidatorLayout
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to customize the Layout used by your appender. Since layout is responsible for serializing log event to a string, I'd check if twitching the layout is less complicated than changing the appender and events going through. Just an idea...

Comment: Yes! That sound like a niche approach instead of modifying Appenders. A custom layout could be used in place of multiple appenders as well

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for creating a delegate class for `Logger` and change all imports from `org.apache.log4j.Logger` to `your.own.Logger`. It's a simple and automatic process — since you consider changing logger calls in the code, I figure you have full access to source code. In the delegate you'd call exactly the methods from log4j Logger, but meddle with the strings first to your heart's content.

I've browsed through the code and prior to version 1.2.15 creating a new `LoggingEvent` from an existing one is impossible without digging through half of the library. From 1.2.15 on there's no problem with it.