# how to create MyLogger?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I use log4j for logging. And I would like to modify methods: warn(..), error(..). I would like to modify message in this methods.
So, is there any way, how to create my own logger?

```
public class MyLogger extends Logger {

protected MyLogger(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
public void error(Object message) {
    message = "test - " + message;

    super.error(message);
}

}
```

And in class call:

```
private static final Logger logger = MyLogger.getLogger(TestClass.class);

logger.error("error message");
```

But it, do not work. Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that:

```
MyLogger.getLogger(TestClass.class)
```

is a `static` method which returns original `Logger` class. `MyLogger` is ignored. The easiest approach is to wrap originally returned `Logger` class in the spirit of [decorator](/questions/tagged/decorator) pattern:

```
public class MyLogger extends Logger {
    final Logger target;
    protected MyLogger(Logger target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void error(Object message) {
        target.error(message);
    }

    //...

}
```

In order to use `MyLogger` decorator you must wrap original logger with it:

```
private static final Logger logger = 
  new MyLogger(Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class));
```

Consider wrapping it in custom factory.

Comment: I think the problem with that method is that if you add the file/line where the log occures to your pattern ("%l" for example), you'll always get "MyLogger" and never the real source.

Comment: Just as a reference: this solution is described at https://books.google.es/books?id=hZBimlxiyAcC&lpg=PA162&ots=QgJm9Y3WZ9&dq=log4j%20decorator&hl=es&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q=log4j%20decorator&f=false

Answer (score 6):

You should never create your own Logger. I have seen many bad reason to create one, but never a good one. If you want to add some contextual information in the log statements, you can use the NDC/MDC feature of Log4J.

http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify the logger - a logger is a just a convenient way to send log messages to the logging framework. The processing of the messages happens in the appenders.

So you have two options:

1. You can tell the main appender (which is attached to the root logger), to process these messages for you. Look here: [LOG4J: Modify logged message using custom appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756308/log4j-modify-logged-message-using-custom-appender)
2. Create a new appender which delegates to an existing appender. That way, you can attach this special appender to only some loggers.

   Just implement `AppenderAttachable<E>` in your appender. Then you can use `<appender-ref .../>` in it's configuration.