# Controlling hibernate exception message

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, logging

Is there any way that Hibernate exception message could be controlled so that it doesn't include the placeholder data for the failed query. 
e.g. for a failed insert query (lets say constraint violation), hibernate logs the exception with the input data. For privacy purpose, this needs to be removed from the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any Hibernate configuration for this, but I would say that this is more suitable for logging configuration anyway.

For example, in log4j you could write [custom appender/layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756308/log4j-modify-logged-message-using-custom-appender) to intercept and replace the messages with the desired content.